# How to wake up sleep(3)ing thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

I want to break `sleep (3)` in another thread from my main thread. To do this, I thought using `raise (sig)` and continuing the code after breaking that system call.

So, which signal should I use to cause `sleep` and return `EINTR`?

The code I've written till now:

```
void *event_loop (void *threadid)
{
    int rc;
    long tid;
        do{
        rc = sleep(20);
        printf ("return from sleep with %d", rc);
        fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
        } while (errno == EINTR);
       tid = (long)threadid;
       printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld! = %d\n", tid);

}

void  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   int sig=SIGABRT ; // which signal???
   int i=0;
   printf("Main THREAD\n");
   for(t=0;t<2;t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, event_loop, (void *)t);
     if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);
       }
     }
    sleep(2);
    printf("rasing signal now from main thread...\n");
    raise(sig);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: The program I attached should be explain,I try to generate EINTR by raise()

Comment: I rephrased your question, so it conveys the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: You don't need signals, signals and threads don't work well for what you want. Instead search google about `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a signal that interrupts a blocking syscall; it is the *delivery* of the signal to the registered handler (that was not installed with SA_RESTART flags) that causes a blocking syscall to interrupt.

Here is an example. The first function is an empty signal handler (long form, so suitable for both POSIX signals, as well as realtime signals `SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-1`). The second function is the handler installer.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void empty_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
}

/* Install empty handler for the specified signal.
 * Returns 0 if success, errno error code otherwise.
*/ 
static int install_empty_handler(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_sigaction = empty_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;

    return 0;
}
```

In your `main()`, let's say you run

```
    if (install_empty_handler(SIGUSR1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handler: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

before creating any threads. (Signal handlers are always assigned for all threads in a process; you cannot set one handler for one thread, and another for another thread. You can check the current thread ID in the installed handler, and do stuff based on it. So, you do not need to install them before creating the threads; it's just that installing the handlers before creating the threads is easier to maintain, and leaves much fewer race windows.)

Let's say you have `pthread_t somethread;` with `somethread` containing the thread identifier for a thread that is in a blocking syscall.

If you call, from any thread,

```
pthread_kill(somethread, SIGUSR1);
```

the `SIGUSR1` signal is sent to that thread.

(Note that the `pthread_kill()` call will return immediately, and you must NOT assume the signal has been delivered yet at that point. You need some other mechanism if you want a delivery notification too. Furthermore, the signal is delivered *first*; the blocking syscall is only interrupted *after the delivery*, and if the system is under a heavy load, there can be a measurable delay between the two. Usually none, I've only seen milliseconds, but make no assumptions about that. If you need notification, have the interrupted syscall do it after it notices it was interrupted.)

The delivery of the signal to the installed `empty_handler()` function causes the blocking syscall in the same thread to interrupt. The call will fail, returning either a short count (for some types of sockets), or `-1` with `errno == EINTR`.

If you instead were to use `raise(SIGUSR1)`, the kernel can pick ANY thread among the threads of the process to handle the signal. (Except for threads that have told the kernel they wish to "block" the signal via [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) or [`sigprocmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html), or if they have inherited such a block from the thread that created that thread.)
Anyway, if that thread is in a blocking syscall, it will be interrupted (due to the delivery of the signal); if it is doing something else, the thread is just "borrowed" for a while, and there is really no sign of the interruption.

---

There **are** cases where this mechanism is useful. In particular, I have used it with timeout timers (using [`timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &event, &timer)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and [`timer_settime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) to set the initial triggering event at the timeout, followed by repeats at rapid short intervals, every few milliseconds) when using external libraries with poor/glitchy timeout support accessing sockets. Even a poor library will not try a blocking read more than a few times in the worst case, if they all fail with an `EINTR` error -- of course, the common, typical case, is that the first one forces the library to report the error immediately. It's the corner cases that really bother me; I only want to publish robust code that is not prone to keeling over just because the moon happens to be in the wrong phase.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the other thread [blocked on a condition variable with a timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_cond_t      cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int interrupted;

#define WAIT_TIME_SECONDS 20
void *event_loop (void *arg)
{
    struct timespec   ts;
    struct timeval    tv;

again:
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    ts.tv_sec  = tv.tv_sec;
    ts.tv_nsec = tv.tv_usec * 1000;
    ts.tv_sec += WAIT_TIME_SECONDS;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!interrupted) {
        int rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);
        if (rc == ETIMEDOUT) {
            printf("Timed out!\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            goto again;
        }
    }
    printf("Woke up!\n");
    interrupted = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    goto again;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, event_loop, NULL);
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        interrupted = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

If you want to have the signalling triggered by a signal like `SIGINT`, either use [sigwait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) in a dedicated thread or use [Semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html). Condition variables aren't async-signal-safe.

Answer (score -1):

When you press Ctr + C, the operating system sends a signal to the process.This will send SIGINT signal.The SIGINT ("program interrupt") is one of the Termination Signals.SIGINT is a special signal as it can be handled (caught) by your program. The default action of SIGINT is program termination. To change the default action of a signal you have to register the signal to be caught. To register a signal in a C program (at least under POSIX systems) there are two functions

1. [signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)
2. [sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act, struct sigaction *oldact);](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction)

These functions require the header signal.h to be included in your C code.

example:

```
#include ...
#include ...
#include<signal.h>
void handler(int sig){
 cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received.\n";
}
int main()
{
  //registering signal by signal function
  signal(SIGINIT,handler);

  //your code

while(++i){
       cout << "Going to sleep...." << endl;
       if( i == 3 ){
          raise( SIGINT);
       }
       sleep(1);
    }
//your code

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't wan't to to use handler .I want to cause interrupt that break the system call in diffrren thread and check it like that:                                     if (errno == EINTR) {..restart the system-call...}

Comment: you can use SIGABRT signal then

Comment: didn't work ,I got  "Aborted (core dumped)" I attached my program ,I hope now my question will be more clear.

Comment: There us no [tag:c++] tag in the question.